# Unable to establish secure connection with the server while using LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect with AD of intranet server. My connection string and other information about it as below:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ip address/CN=Users,DC=domainname,DC=com"></add>
 </connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

My problem is sometimes I am able to connect to server but most of the time I am getting an error keep saying:

> "Unable to establish secure connection with the server"

The line where I am getting this error is :

```
Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
```